# Content vs style in answers and how to handle duplicates vs edits?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-answers

We have [two revisions on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object/684692#684692) and the problem boils down to one of style vs content. **I'd like to see this clarified, and my edited reverted.** This is the **original** code snippet:

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

This is my **modified** code snippet,

```
for (let key in obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
  // code;
}
```

I have two problems with leaving things the way they are here:

1. The chosen answer has an inferior style, but the same content. This has the potential to spread the practice (against the convention in every langauge). We want the top most answer to represent the best of that method. Here both answers are simply providing the `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` method.
2. As professionals, we need to be able to reasonably discern between content and style. If the results are logically isomorphic, we need to accept them as edits rather than duplicate the content. If we refuse this guideline, we'll have thousands of duplicates and no method of arguing against people who think they should get to duplicate answers merely to provide a slight modification in style.

There is **no** reason to ever write the whole body of a *for..in* statement in a conditional. You just increase your nesting, but changing this is a *style* change. You're not changing the flow of the code. They're both right in content by using the `obj.hasOwnProperty()` method. The chosen answer just wrote his conditional backwards: that doesn't warrant another answer. We're professionals we can resolve these issues over style in comments or minor edits.

```
for ( cond ) {
  if ( cond2 ) { 
    // code requiring two indentions
  }
}
```

is always better written as

```
for ( cond ) {
  if ( !cond2 ) { continue; }
  // code requiring one indention
}
```

As an alternative point, I could see rejecting the second answer entirely for just adding a point of style. Perhaps that answer should be a comment on the first? But, it is totally unreasonable to have two answers here.

[I also added a title, but I don't think that is being called into question.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0d27f94a-a534-4f92-9478-0c9b20444c4a/view-source)

Comment: The edit fundamentally changed _how_ the code works, ignoring compatibility with older browsers by changing the code to ES6. Code edits like that are unacceptable, _especially_ on high traffic questions like that one. Furthermore, you expanded the answer with new code. You _just don't do that_. Write an answer of your own. If it's so much better, it'll get enough votes.

Comment: @Cerbrus What are you talking about ES6? This is why I don't think you know how to read a revision log. What part [*my* commit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0d27f94a-a534-4f92-9478-0c9b20444c4a/view-source) had anything to do with ES6? You were already [corrected on this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31039904#31039904) (which you lacked the honor to tag me in or address me directly). As said in chat, I highly suggest you check out R2, and R3 (my commits). **I added NO new code whatsoever. Just a minor style change per above.**

Comment: That _"correction"_ in chat you keep referring to misunderstood my intentions. I intentionally reverted the answer to revision _one_. Like I said: You fundamentally changed _how_ an highly upvoted answer works. ___Don't___. That _"minor change in style"_ is the first edit on that answer in over ___6___ years. It is your _personal_ preference, and the edit was completely unwarranted.

Comment: I didn't fundamentally change anything. You keep saying [I added the es6 commit to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15821a8f-1210-42ce-aa4b-77969e656871/view-source) which I didn't; it was added by Lukas. You reverted the answer to R1 not because you like R1 (there is nothing fundamentally different from my commit), but because you can't read a commit log. That's why you keep using terms like *"fundamental"*, *"es6"* and phrases like "*how it works*". Any of which and I would grant I was wrong. **Nothing works differently in my commit.**

Comment: You changed the `if` statement to work differently, with a `continue`. That is fundamentally different code. That is _your personal preference_, and that is completely unnecessary. By the way, instead of linking to a specific revision's source, link to the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/684692/revisions), instead. Then other users can at least see what's been edited.

Comment: Please stop falling back on ad-hominem attacks like _"You don't know how to read the revision log"_,  _"you don't know how [to code](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31171179#31171179)"_ and _"[you're prideful](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31171179#31171179)"._ It really doesn't work in your favour.

Comment: Even if `let` is not ES6, it has serious [compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility). That's not a style change. And even if it _were_ a style change, who are you to change a +2k voted answer that hasn't been touched since it was first posted, 6 years ago? Don't edit code!

Comment: No that's inferred on your behavior, and not just from me but in chat by [Kendall Frey](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31039904#31039904). Defend your claim: tell me what my commit has to do with ES6, or a *fundamental* change that modifies *how it works*.

Comment: @Cerbrus so your argument is fundamentally not about the question. You just don't like the fact that I edited an old answer? Know what? tough! That feature is there to be used, and I used it. It should have been edited right away and it wasn't. That's easily fixed because there is no restriction imposed. Perhaps if you want to fundamentally change the way SO works, you should open a thread about it.

Comment: Multiple other users in the chat room agreed that the edits were bad. A ___moderator___ rolled back the edits, _including yours_. If you want to dispute that, take it up with said moderator. I'm done trying to explain how editing works.

Comment: For other users reading this: [___Here's___ the remainder of the discussion about these edits](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31041363#31041363), in the JS chatroom. You'll see I'm not the only one that's of the opinion these edits should've been reverted.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: "*That feature is there to be used, and I used it.*" And his power to revert your edit is there to be used, and he used it. What's your problem?

Comment: Editing an existing and highly-upvoted answer with code that is less compatible and could be considered poor practices is well outside of what edits are meant for and just short of sabotage. There's a reason that a *moderator* rolled back all of your edits in that thread.

Answer (score 14):

Your grievances with the code, however justified they may be, read like something you'd see in a code review.  That said, all of the grievances you've expressed are still an *opinion* on the quality of the code, and do not do anything to improve its current correctness.

What would changing this code have accomplished?  It may show a newer and revised style, but that doesn't automatically mean that editing this answer makes sense.  The edit does nothing for the **correctness** or **accuracy** of the answer.  In fact, it actively *changes* aspects of the answer which have a stronger chance of making it incorrect (and as a strictly personal opinion, `continue` in loops is a cardinal sin).

This edit shouldn't have happened.  Rolling it back was the right choice.  If you want to add an answer which encapsulates the new ES6 approach, you're encouraged to do that *instead*.

Comment: This is what I've been saying to Evan before (new) comments were wiped on the answer. +1